# Is it possible to have an individual marker color for each point in a QScatterSeries?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qtcharts

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811328/is-it-possible-to-have-a-individual-marker-size-for-each-point-in-a-qscatterseri/50813089) shows that it is possible to have an individual marker size for each point in a QScatterSeries. What about an indiviual marker color for each point?

Comment: In the other example you already iterate the items, so instead of changing the scale, change the color (it may be called a pen or brush, but look at the actual declaration of the type in use by leveraging your IDE’s go-to-declaration functionality).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't understand "by leveraging your IDE’s go-to-declaration functionality" part. How is that linked to a pen or brush? Could you possibly explain how you do it using qtcreator in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circles are QGraphicsEllipseItem so you can cast them, and then use the setBrush method to set the color:

```
for(int index= 0; index < series->count(); index++){
    QPointF p =  chart->mapToPosition(series->at(index) , series);
    QGraphicsItem *it = view.itemAt(view.mapFromScene(p));
    it->setTransformOriginPoint(it->boundingRect().center());
    it->setScale(data[index].s);
    if(QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse = qgraphicsitem_cast(it)){
        QColor color = QColor::fromRgb(QRandomGenerator::global()->generate());;
        ellipse->setBrush(color);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. You answered two of my questions in a row. Somehow, I didn't get notification that this question has been answered.

Comment: Only 1 series points is getting colored, the other series are not getting colored, it fails at the graphicsitem_cast